# How to get the data points of a time series that are not in another time series using Promql?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

For example if I have two time series like below.

```
metric_1{id=1} 1
metric_1{id=2} 1
metric_1{id=3} 1
```

```
metric_2{id=1} 1
metric_2{id=3} 1
```

I would like to get this as the query result since `id=2` is not in `metric_2`.

```
{id=2} 1
```

Similar to this question [Comparison Query to Compare Two SQL Server Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411666/comparison-query-to-compare-two-sql-server-tables) but in Promql. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you basically want to drop all series in `metric_1` that have a value for the label `id` that can be also found in the series `metric_2`. In SQL this would look something like this:

```
metric_1 left outer join metric_2 on id
```

In Prometheus first you might come across `group_left`. (read more about this here ["Left joins in PromQL"](https://www.robustperception.io/left-joins-in-promql). But this will not work. Instead, we use the `unless` operator.

```
metric_1 unless on (id) metric_2
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I somehow missed reading this in the docs. Here it is in case someone needs it https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators. Also more info and an example using `unless` can be found here https://www.robustperception.io/absent-alerting-for-scraped-metrics.